# Как решить проблему с composer?

Tags: php, yii2, composer

решил установить для yii https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget - но текущая версия не устанавливается (только @dev). На форуме (уже не вспомню на каком) прочёл, что нужно:

```
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0-beta4"
```

воспользовался командой и теперь вот такая картина

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я могу удалить этот каталог и пользоваться composer через конечную папку (проекта), но такой вариант не работает (в плане yii2-date-picker-widget), поэтому хочу разрешить вопрос с global...

как это исправить?

Answer (score 2):

`fxp-composer-plugin` ожидает существование метода `parseLinks()`, которого нет в установленной версии композера. ЕМНИП она была добавлена где-то в пределах от полугода до трех месяцев назад, попробуйте обновить композер; если я неправ и композер свежий, попробуйте установить более свежую версию плагина (beta4, по-моему, была еще до релиза yii 2).

Answer (score 1):

Asset Plugin нужен для установки расширений с использованием JavaScript и CSS (так называемых asset'ов) без установки NPM или Bower.

Плагин устанавливается глобально для всего composer'а.

Чтобы иметь возможность его в дальнейшем автоматически обновлять лучше указывать не конкретную версию, а ветку.

Ну и сам composer лучше тоже регулярно обновлять.

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0"
composer global update
composer self-update
```